# How to change the scope of currently run file to its parent folder in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I need to change the path of the currently run python file to point to its parent folder.

I have to create a package that encapsulates code that imports functionality from subdirectories, and at the same time the code needs to be executable from the subdirectories.

I have the following code

```
|--device1
|  |--ControlModule
|  |  |--control.py
|  |--ViewModule
|  |  |--view.py
|  |--main.py
| 
|--device2
|  |--ControlModule
|  |  |--control.py
|  |--ViewModule
|  |  |--view.py
|  |--main.py
```

Each main.py imports the control functions from the corresponding modules.

file: *device[1-2]/main.py*

```
from ControlModule.Controller import control
```

Then the modules import functions from each other in the following way

file: *device[1-2]/ControlModue/control.py*

```
form ViewModule.views import Viewer
```

The program is then run with a *main.py* for each device and works fine. I need to keep this functionality - the *main.py* run from each subdirectory should run the code for the according device.

My task is to pack this code into a package, that contains all the devices. I created a package in the parent directory, like this:

```
|--all_devices  
   |--device1
   |  |--ControlModule
   |  |  |--control.py
   |  |--ViewModule
   |  |  |--view.py
   |  |--main.py
   | 
   |--device2
   |  |--ControlModule
   |  |  |--control.py
   |  |--ViewModule
   |  |  |--view.py
   |  |--main.py
   |
   |--pyproject.toml
   |--testme.py
```

doing so, I had to adapt the control.py and view.py files, so that they point to the correct devices. This means the following adaptations

file: *device1/ControlModule.py*

```
from device1.ViewModule.views import Viewer
```

file: *device2/ControlModule.py*

```
from device2.ViewModule.views import Viewer
```

This way, when I install the package (that I called "all_devices") into an virtual environemnt I can just call

```
from device1.ControlMode.Controller import controll
```

and it works.

This way however I broke the relative links in the *main.py* for each device. Running */device1/main.py* doesn't find the modules anymore - the interpreter is looking for *device1.ViewModule.views*, and it can't find it, as it is run from */device1/* directory already, so the path doesn't exist.

I was trying to fix this in two ways, both failed:

1. changing the "scope" of the *main.py* file to the parent folder, so that the links to imports would make sense. I tried with *os.chdir("..")* - this dosesn't work (I guess this is because I am changing only the path variable, not the actual scope of the application)
2. making an if case before the includes in modules, so that the correct path would be used, depending how ist the program started. precisely speaking I added this to device1/ControleModule.py:

```
if __file__ == "main.py":
    form ViewModule.views import Viewer
else:
    from device1.ViewModule.views import Viewer
```

this also didn't work (the idea was that other files running the package would bever be called "main.py")

I would be grateful for any ideas on how to fix this issue.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to import modules using a path relative to the parent directory. does this help? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-import-from-parent-directory/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem by adding relative paths to the imports.
I added these lines to each *main.py*

```
current = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
parent = os.path.dirname(current)
sys.path.append(parent)
form device1.ControleModule.Controller import control
```